# How to pass multiple input id into a stored procedure and get the ids that have all input ids?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

My goal is that when the user chooses the product, the application will export the supplier that provides both products. However, if I use a stored procedure, the input must be a fixed value so I can't put a listId like C#.

So, how can I just put a list of Id into the store and I have produced supplier business id of the added productId. See my table below and `InventoryOfSentoId` is `ProductId`:

[image]

- If input is 1 then output is supplierid 1 and 3
- If input is 2, 3 then output is supplierid 3

Comment: are you trying to send a list of ids to the stored procedure ?

Comment: use `Table-Valued Parameters` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: There are at least three different ways to achieve this. Table valued parameters (as Squirrel commented), XML and (probably easiest of all) comma separated strings (the separator can be anything). If you edit your post to show in what form you currently have the list, I can give you an example of the use of any of these three.

Comment: i use Sql server 2014, it doesn't support STRING_SPLIT

Comment: In my form, I want to use combobox with datasource is all Supplier Id have same ProductId which is taken from all Checked Row in DataGridViewListProduct, so if 4 rows was checked, and combobox will dropdown a list of SupplierId which have 4 product with same id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2014, it is easy to create your own split function.  The one I use is the following (but you can google for others that are more efficient, particularly if your list is long):

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit](
@sDelimiter VARCHAR(5) -- delimiter that separates items
  , @sInputList VARCHAR(max) -- List of delimited items
) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(max))

BEGIN
DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(max)
WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
 BEGIN
 SELECT
  @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
  @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

 IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
  INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
 END

IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
 INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
RETURN
END
```

You will then be able to achieve what you want with:

```
declare @demo table (SupplierID int, InventoryOfSentoID int)
declare @list varchar(10) = '2,3'
declare @ids table (SentoID int)
declare @cnt int

INSERT INTO @demo VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(2,5),(3,3),(3,2),(3,1)

INSERT INTO @ids 
SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplit(',',@list)

SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) FROM @ids

SELECT SupplierID FROM @demo d
INNER JOIN  @ids i
ON i.SentoID = d.InventoryOfSentoID
GROUP BY SupplierID
HAVING COUNT(*) = @cnt
```

By way of explanation, note the use of the `HAVING` restriction. This is to ensure that only those suppliers who supply all the elements in the list are returned.  If you did not have this restriction, the resultset would include supplierid 1, which from your question I presumed you wanted to exclude.

Comment: There are far better options out there than a `WHILE` for splitting strings. A `WHILE` is the slowest option. I would suggest an XML Splitter, or `DelimitesSplit8k_Lead`.

Comment: @Larnu I agree with you, that's why I suggested googling for better ones!  I only ever have short lists to split, so I've never been too concerned, and I have used this one for more years than I care to remember.  Old habits …

Comment: Fair, I just wondered why you gave what is considered the worst solution, when you know there *are* better ones. :) *Hopefully* the OP will research those other (better) options.